# Why does passing this dataframe through my function change the original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
def index_data(self, weights, price_data):
    i = 0
    for column in price_data: 
        price_data[column+'_weighted']=price_data[column]*weights[i]
        i=i+1
    return price_data
```

I have written this function to help me calculate weighted returns from a list of assets.

I have a dataframe of prices (index is time) and iterate through each column, and multiply that column by the specific weight (weights is a list, in the same order as the columns).

I am creating a new column so I may double check that the code is working as intended (preserving original returns).

I am passing the original dataframe through the function, and setting the function equal to a new variable.

The new variable turns out correct -- but the old dataframe changes as well! I'm not sure why it changes. I thought the variable passed to the function would just be a copy, and the original dataframe would stay as it is.

Comment: python doesn't copy value to function for complex structures. It sends reference to this structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python passes arguments by assignment.

Consider this:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
df2 = df1
df2[0][1] = 9
print(df1)
```

You'll see that `df1` is modified, even though you only modified `df2`. This is because `df2` isn't assigned a copy of `df1`, but it's assigned the same object. The same happens when passing to a function. https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference

Note that the DataFrame you're returning is just the same object yet again.